# Membership and Authentication with ASP.NET in a 3-tier design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

I recently got Visual Studio 2012 professional and am working on a design for a web application.  I'm set on using the 3-tier design with MVC 4 as the top tier and WCF as the middle tier.  I also want to use as much of the 'out of the box' functionality that Microsoft provides as possible(considering the $ cost).

Looking at the MVC 4 Internet Application template, I notice that it uses LocalDB with WebSecurity for creating and authenticating accounts.  I plan on sending requests to create and authentication users through the middle tier but want similar functionality.

How does Microsoft want me to do this?  It sound like I need to implement ASP.NET Membership, Roles and Profiles in addition to WCF authentication and role services.  Does this sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET Membership system does not work with a three-tier design by default.  You could implement your own custom membership provider, or you could just skip it and implement your own IIdentity and IPrincipal interfaces.

You may find this article helpful:

http://elysianonline.com/programming/wcf-wrapper-for-asp-net-membership/